# get the sum of children nodes right below for every parent in a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table `objective` with columns `id, label, cost, parent_id`
and i have this query

```
select 
b.id,
b.parent_id,
b.label,
b.cost
from objective b
start with b.parent_id is null
connect by 
prior b.id=b.parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY b.id
```

only a leaf (and sometimes a parent of a leaf) has the column `cost` not null the others are almost always null, is it possible to get the cost of every node (summing the cost of the nodes right below) or not.

i know it can be done with join and sum but i thought maybe there is a simpler way to do it.
if this was the table content :

```
ID  PARENT_ID   LABEL   COST
1   null        A       0
2   1           B       1
3   2           C       3
4   1           D       0
5   4           E       3
6   5           F       7
7   4           G       5
```

the result should be something like this :

```
ID  PARENT_ID   LABEL   COST    CALCULATED_COST
1   null        A       0       15(meaning 0 is a wrong value) 
2   1           B       1       3 (meaning 1 is a wrong value)
3   2           C       3       3
4   1           D       0       12
5   4           E       3       7 (meaning 3 is a wrong value)
6   5           F       7       7
7   4           G       5       5
```

Comment: Why 15 and not 19 (0+1+3+0+3+7+5) for the first row?

Comment: because there are some values that have been inserted wrong by users and so i need to  only rely on the values of the leaf rows (which are all correct values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> only a leaf (and sometimes a parent of a leaf) has the column cost not null the others are almost always null

If the rule is that "only a leaf or a parent of a leaf have a non-null `cost` and the others are **always** null" then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       label,
       COALESCE(PRIOR cost, 0) + COALESCE(cost, 0) AS cost
FROM   objective
START WITH
       parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       id
```

If the rule is that "any row can have a non-null `cost`" then you will need to parse the data structure in both directions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       label,
       ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cost), 0)
         FROM   objective c
         START WITH c.id = o.id
         CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id -- Reverse the direction
       ) AS cost
FROM   objective o
START WITH
       parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       id
```

or use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, parent_id, label, cost) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, label, COALESCE(cost, 0)
  FROM   objective
  WHERE  parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT o.id, o.parent_id, o.label, COALESCE(o.cost, 0) + r.cost
  FROM   objective o
         INNER JOIN rsqfc r
         ON (r.id = o.parent_id)
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT *
FROM   rsqfc;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FV477UUU)

---

#### Update

If you are looking to sum the cost for a row and all its descendants then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       label,
       cost,
       ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cost), 0)
         FROM   objective c
         START WITH c.id = o.id
         CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
       ) AS total_cost
FROM   objective o
START WITH
       parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       id;
```

Which, for the sample data outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE objective ( id, parent_id, label, cost ) AS
SELECT 1, NULL, 'A', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 'C', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'D', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4, 'E', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 5, 'F', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 4, 'G', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | PARENT_ID | LABEL | COST | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | A | 0 | 19 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | C | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | D | 0 | 15 |
| 5 | 4 | E | 3 | 10 |
| 6 | 5 | F | 7 | 7 |
| 7 | 4 | G | 5 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D4-wYLha)

---

#### Update 2:

If you only want to total the descendants that are leaves then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       label,
       cost,
       ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cost), 0)
         FROM   objective c
         WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
         START WITH c.id = o.id
         CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
       ) AS total_cost
FROM   objective o
START WITH
       parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       id;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | PARENT_ID | LABEL | COST | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | A | 0 | 15 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | C | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | D | 0 | 12 |
| 5 | 4 | E | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 5 | F | 7 | 7 |
| 7 | 4 | G | 5 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_k5QNqwb)

Comment: The question is about aggregation of descendants (if I understood the phrase "summing the cost of *the nodes right below*" correctly), so recursion should be reversed

Comment: this solution (the 3rd or 2nd) returns correct values only for the parents of leafs, leafs costs returned by this query = leaf cost + its parent's costm and all the other nodes have cost=0

Comment: i think i might have not explained my problem clearly, i have edited the question now if you think you can help me out and thanks

Comment: @imstuckaf Updated to calculate the cost of a row and its descendants; however I don't get the same output as your question so you might need to clarify how you are calculating the totals.

Comment: the total cost of id=5 is not 10 but 7 (3 is a wrong value and needs to updated by the sum of the children)

Comment: @imstuckaf Updated again to only total the costs for each row and its descendants that are also leaves.